# How to Pass Or Call Entity Frame Work Connection String My Code Attached ?? Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, connection-string

I am getting error "The underlying provider failed on Open." actually i haven't call entity frame work connection string my code is,

```
 InspectionEntities dbContext = new InspectionEntities();
```

how to pass entity fram work connection string when "InspectionEntities" is as ,

```
namespace DataAccessManager
{
    public class InspectionEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        public InspectionEntities();
        public InspectionEntities(EntityConnection connection);
        public InspectionEntities(string connectionString);
```

and inspection is as,

```
[assembly: EdmSchemaAttribute()]

namespace DataAccessManager
{
    #region Contexts

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class InspectionEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new InspectionEntities object using the connection string found in the 'InspectionEntities' section of the application configuration file.
        /// </summary>
        public InspectionEntities() : base("name=InspectionEntities", "InspectionEntities")
        {
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new InspectionEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public InspectionEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "InspectionEntities")
        {
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new InspectionEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public InspectionEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "InspectionEntities")
        {
            OnContextCreated();
        }

        #endregion
```

and my connection string is,

```
<add name="InspectionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Inspection.csdl|res://*/Inspection.ssdl|res://*/Inspection.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=*****\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Inspection;User ID=sa;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

InspectionEntities dbContext = new InspectionEntities();
```

when i use its object dbcontext in getting data it give me error for underlying provider failed on open

How to pass or call entity connection string in here,

`InspectionEntities dbContext = new InspectionEntities("name=InspectionEntities");` ????

i am getting same here

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass the connection string to your context constructor. Instead change it in the `web.config` file.

The error you are receiving points that the SQL server name or instance name is specified incorrectly or there is a firewall blocking the connection. If it would be username/password issue you would get an error saying that login is not possible.